# How do I remove all children elements from a node and then apply them again with different color and size?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

So I have the next force layout graph code for setting nodes, links and other elements:

```
var setLinks = function ()
{
    link = visualRoot.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(graphData.links)
        .enter().append("svg:line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return nodeStrokeColorDefault; })
        .style("stroke", function (d) { return fill(d); })
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    graphData.links.forEach(function (d)
    {
        linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
    });
};


var setNodes = function ()
{
    node = visualRoot.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graphData.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("title", function (d) { return d.name; })
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", function (d, i) { loadAdditionalData(d.userID, this); })
        .call(force.drag)
        .on("mouseover", fadeNode(.1)).on("mouseout", fadeNode(1));
};

//append the visual element to the node
var appendVisualElementsToNodes = function ()
{
    node.append("circle")
        .attr("id", function (d) { return "circleid_" + d.id; })
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return 0; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return 0; })
        .attr("r", function (d) { return getNodeSize(d); })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return getNodeColor(d); })
        .style("stroke", function (d) { return nodeStrokeColorDefault; })
        .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return nodeStrokeWidthDefault; });

    //context menu:
    d3.selectAll(".circle").on("contextmenu", function (data, index)
    {
        d3.select('#my_custom_menu')
          .style('position', 'absolute')
          .style('left', d3.event.dx + "px")
          .style('top', d3.event.dy + "px")
          .style('display', 'block');

        d3.event.preventDefault();
    });
    //d3.select("svg").node().oncontextmenu = function(){return false;};

    node.append("image")
        .attr("class", "image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.profile_image_url; })//"Images/twitterimage_2.png"
        .attr("x", -12)
        .attr("y", -12)
        .attr("width", 24)
        .attr("height", 24);

    node.append("svg:title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + d.description; });
};
```

Now, the colors and size dependencies changed and I need to redraw the graph circles (+all appended elements) with different color and radius. Having problem with it.

I can do this:

```
visualRoot.selectAll(".circle").remove();
```

but I have all the images that I attached to `'.circles'` still there.

In any way, any help will be appreciated, let me know if the explanation is not clear enough, I will try to fix it.

P.S. what is the difference between `graphData.nodes`  and `d3.selectAll('.nodes')`?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Your answer will work, but for posterity, these methods are more generic.

Remove all children from HTML:

```
d3.select("div.parent").html("");
```

Remove all children from SVG/HTML:

```
d3.select("g.parent").selectAll("*").remove();
```

The `.html("")` call works with my SVG, but it might be a side effect of using [innerSVG](https://code.google.com/p/innersvg/).

Comment: Unfortunately .html("") does not work in Safari. Works fine in all other browsers.

Comment: @glyph: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43661877/1587329 for the official way to do this

Answer (score 9):

My first advice is that you should read the `d3.js` API about selections: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

You have to understand how the `enter()` command works ([API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selection_enter)). The fact that you have to use it to handle new nodes has a meaning which will help you.

Here is the basic process when you deal with `selection.data()`:

- first you want to "attach" some data to the selection. So you have:

  ```
    var nodes = visualRoot.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graphData.nodes)
  ```
- Then you can modify all nodes each times data is changed (this will do exactly what you want). If for example you change the radius of old nodes which are in the new dataset you loaded

  ```
    nodes.attr("r", function(d){return d.radius})
  ```
- Then, you have to handle new nodes, for this you have to select the new nodes, this is what `selection.enter()` is made for:

  ```
    var nodesEnter = nodes.enter()
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("r", function(d){return d.radius})
  ```
- Finally you certainly want to remove the nodes you don't want anymore, to do this, you have to select them, this is what `selection.exit()` is made for.

  ```
    var nodesRemove = nodes.exit().remove()
  ```

A good example of the whole process can also be found on the API wiki: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-exit

Comment: HI Chris,

thanks for the suggestions and points. The fact is, that I do not have  new data.. Data still the same. Everything is the same. I don't want to do the whole force process again. 

As far as I understand (correct me if I am wrong). All I have to do is to

Comment: all I have to do is to find dom elements with '.circle' class and their children. Remove them. Find the svg elements with '.node' class and reapply 'attach' process for svg circles and other visuals described in 'applyvisualelements' function, but this time when the radius will be calculated, it will be calculated differently.

Comment: in any way, I have resolved it very easily, 
   visualRoot.selectAll(".circle").remove();
        visualRoot.selectAll(".image").remove();

Answer (score 9):

If you want to remove the element itself, just use [`element.remove()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_remove), as you did. In case you just want to remove the content of the element, but keep the element as-is, you can use f.ex.

```
visualRoot.selectAll(".circle").html(null);
visualRoot.selectAll(".image").html(null);
```

instead of `.html("")` (I wasn't sure which element's children you want deleted). This ***keeps the element itself, but cleans all included content***. It [the official way to do this](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_html), so should work cross-browser.

PS: you wanted to change the circle sizes. Have you tried

```
d3.selectAll(".circle").attr("r", newValue);
```

Comment: `html(null)` isn't working for me in Internet Explorer 11

Comment: @Robert: " A null value will clear the content." Seems like a bug. Anything reported to console?

Comment: Nope, no errors or warnings. Just returns the selected object. `d3.select($0).html('')` from the selected answer doesn't work for me in IE either, but `d3.select($0).selectAll('*').remove()` does work.

Comment: @Robert: Do you want to [report this](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/new)?

Answer (score 7):

in this way, I have resolved it very easily,

```
visualRoot.selectAll(".circle").remove();
visualRoot.selectAll(".image").remove();
```

and then I just re-added visual elements which were rendered differently because the code for calculating radius and color had changed properties. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To remove all element from a node:

```
var siblings = element.parentNode.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < siblings.length; j++) {
        siblings[i].parentElement.removeChild(siblings[j]);
    }
}`
```

Comment: You seam to quote something, what is the source?

Comment: Do you really need to also remove all those nodes from their own nodes. Surely the DOM recommended method would suffice as the nodes wouldn't be off the current node don't need to be ripped apart too.

Comment: var element = document.getElementById("top");
while (element.firstChild) {
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}