# Is there an equivalent of jquery .empty() in d3?

Tags: jquery, d3.js

In jQuery I can clear/empty a div with the following:

```
$("#graph").empty()
```

so the above command would clear/empty the following div if it had any tags inside it `<div id="graph"></div>`.

Is there an equivalent way to do this is d3?

see my [PLUNKER here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NNPNQVXg9Eff8WMT0zjb?p=preview)

Snippet of Plunker code here:

```
<div id="mylist">hello test1</div>


<div id="graph">hello test2</div>

<script>        
        $("#graph").empty() // comment out to not empty the div
</script>
```

---

### EDIT1

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wba8CaJ4T1Ii5eYCRNBd?p=preview) for my reference based on answer below.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422198/how-do-i-remove-all-children-elements-from-a-node-and-them-apply-them-again-with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

You could use `.html("")` and basically wipe the html content of the element you have selected.

Or if you want to delete a specific d3 selection you can go for `.remove()`.

The remove method will remove the selection itself, whereas emptying out the html just takes care of all child nodes.

So for your case probably `d3.select('#graph').html("")`.

I modified your Plunker to use d3: https://plnkr.co/edit/V2tYVxOTbzMUX3D7m57L?p=preview

Answer (score 8):

The [official way to do this](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_html) is to use `.html(null)`, as in

```
d3.select("#graph").html(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Expecting that you are using <svg> </svg> for writing all your code in d3 (as we do), so you can use the following code to get things cleared when required:

```
//removing prior svg elements ie, clean up svg 
d3.select('svg').selectAll("*").remove();
```