# D3 removing old children and then appending new ones with their own attributes

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I need help with one task. When you click a button only text is overwritten but I want to remove all the children of the group with certain id and fill it with children of #refresh.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <style>
    body {
        background-color: #000000;
    }</style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <button onclick="refreshSvgElement('#c3a4ca3d-da2d-4b94-9a35-1088ba0cac19')">Change</button>
    <svg id="refresh">
        <text class="text" x="0.40576159954071" y="51.4495124816895" fill="#E0E0E0" font-family="Calibri" font-size="55.4" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200,200)">BLUE</text>
    </svg>
    <svg id="main_window" position="fixed" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 8074 4098">
        <g>
            <g id="c3a4ca3d-da2d-4b94-9a35-1088ba0cac19">
                <text class="text" x="0.40576159954071" y="51.4495124816895" fill="#E0E0E0" font-family="Calibri" font-size="55.4" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200,200)">RED</text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
    </body>

</html>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"> </script>
<script>    
    function refreshSvgElement(id) {

    var refreshElement = d3.select("#refresh");

    var selection = d3.select(id)
        .select("text")
        <!-- .remove() -->
        <!-- .append("text") -->
        .text(refreshElement.text());
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove all children elements from a node and then apply them again with different color and size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422198/how-do-i-remove-all-children-elements-from-a-node-and-then-apply-them-again-with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Store `selection` as a `var`, then select all current text and use `.remove()`, then append new text.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }</style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <button onclick="refreshSvgElement('#c3a4ca3d-da2d-4b94-9a35-1088ba0cac19')">Change</button>
    <svg id="refresh">
        <text class="text" x="0.40576159954071" y="51.4495124816895" fill="#E0E0E0" font-family="Calibri" font-size="55.4" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200,200)">BLUE</text>
    </svg>
    <svg id="main_window" position="fixed" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 8074 4098">
        <g>
            <g id="c3a4ca3d-da2d-4b94-9a35-1088ba0cac19">
                <text class="text" x="0.40576159954071" y="51.4495124816895" fill="#E0E0E0" font-family="Calibri" font-size="55.4" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200,200)">RED</text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
    </body>

</html>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"> </script>
<script>    
    function refreshSvgElement(id) {

    var refreshElement = d3.select("#refresh");
    console.log(refreshElement.text())
    var selection = d3.select(id)
        selection.selectAll("text").remove();
        selection.append("text").text(refreshElement.text()).attr("x", "0.5").attr("y", "50");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: When I do it it disappears. I can't get anything in after remove()

Comment: The `remove` statement cannot be applied with an `append` statement via method chaining. You will have to do `selection.remove()` then `selection.append()` as shown above.

Comment: Unfortunately, same result. RED disappeared but BLUE won't show up.

Comment: I updated my answer. It does work, it was just appending the text under the button. I moved is slightly to show it does appear.

Comment: I didn't see it because of the black background. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing. BLUE has same attributes as RED and I need them. How do I access them. Blue has its own coordinates, font-family, transform ...